# How to display two image collections(using Unsplash API) through use of tabs in Flutter?

Tags: api, flutter

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(StartPage());
}

class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Assignment",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Assignment 1"),
        bottom: TabBar(
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
          labelColor: Colors.amber,
          tabs: [
            new Tab(child: Text("Tab 1"),),

            new Tab(child: Text("Tab 2"),),
          ],
          controller: _tabController,
          indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,),
        bottomOpacity: 1,
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          new Text("Tab View 1"),
          new Text("Tab View 2"),
        ],
        controller: _tabController,),
    );
  }
}
```

I am building an app, I have to display two sets of image collections through use of two tab views.
I am fetching images from unsplash api. Can someone guide me through?

I have Built the tab bars and two tab bar views.
I am not able to understand how to fetch images from Unsplash API and display them in two different tabs.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I have added the code, it is the basic code to make two tabs. How do I add image collections from unsplash API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I had to do such a thing and I did it.Follow these steps:

- First follow till step 8 as per this link: https://bytestotech.com/2020/03/use-unsplash-api-to-fetch-images-for-flutter-app-app-development-wallpaper-flutter-app/
- next declare all of them like this

  ```
     List data = [];    
     List data2 = [];    
     List<String> imgUrl = [];    
     List<String> imgUr2 = [];    
     List<String> name1 = [];    
     List<String> name2 = [];    
     bool flag1 = false;    
     bool flag2 = false;    
     String url1 =
         "https://api.unsplash.com/photos?client_id=<YOUR ACCESS KEY";    
     String url2 =
         "https://api.unsplash.com/photos?client_id="YOUR ACCESS KEY";
  ```

**NOTE**:You will have to slightly modify the url as per your desired API link

- Next you will have to fetch the data from the API using the http request.So make sure you add the dependency in pubspec.yaml file .The code is self explanatory.If any doubts do feel free to comment

  ```
             getData() async 
            {
               http.Response response = await http.get(url1);
               data = json.decode(response.body);
               _assign();
               setState(()
              {
                 flag1 = true;
               });
              }

                 _assign() 
                  {
                   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                  {
                     imgUrl.add(data.elementAt(i)["urls"]["regular"]);

                   }
                 }
  ```
- Get the data in init function

  ```
              @override
             void initState()
             {

               getData();
               getData2();
               super.initState();
               _scrollController.addListener(() 
               {
                 if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
                     _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent)
               {
                   getData();
                   getData2();
                 }
               }
            );
             }
  ```
- under tab bar use this code:

  ```
    TabBarView
             (
               children: [
                     GridView.builder(
                     controller: _scrollController,
                     itemCount: imgUrl.length,
                     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                     shrinkWrap: true,
                     primary: false,
                     gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                         mainAxisSpacing: 20,crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                         crossAxisCount: 2),
                     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                       return Container(

                         child: !flag1
                             ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                             : Image.network(imgUrl[index], fit: BoxFit.cover),
                       );
                     }),

                 GridView.builder(
                     controller: _scrollController,
                     itemCount: imgUr2.length,
                     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                     shrinkWrap: true,
                     primary: false,
                     gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                       mainAxisSpacing: 20,crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                         crossAxisCount: 2),
                     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                       return Container(

                         child: !flag1
                             ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                             : Image.network(imgUr2[index], fit: BoxFit.cover),

                       );
                     }),
               ],
   ),
  ```

Answer (score 0):

hi here is what I found.
Function to fetch images through API and decode the JSON format:

```
Future<String> getjsondata() async {
 try{
    var response= await http.get(‘https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos
     per_page=30&client_id=it1PXzVQRnxgz8v8hazcst7
     G9rNfXk1qiS8FgHTTMMk&query=${_search}');
   setState(() {
     var converted = json.decode(response.body);
     data=converted["results"];
        });
     }
     catch(e){}
    return "success";
   }
```

To display images in ListView or in youcase tabs:

```
ListView.builder(itemCount: data == null?0:data.length,
  itemBuilder: (
      BuildContext context, int
      index){
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Card(
              child: new Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(
                      data[index][‘urls’][‘small’],
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

here is the link of full code I found [link](https://tech2bropro.blogspot.com/2020/03/use-unsplash-api-to-fetch-images-for.html)

Comment: Thank you for the help, Can you help me with integration of this to GridView format and displaying in tab bar view?

Comment: Can you Explain the process of adding the API?